# Generate unique 5 character string?

Tags: javascript

How can I generate a UNIQUE (not random) 5 character string in javascript.
I do not want to use Math.random() as it does not ensure uniqueness.
It should contain characters from a-z,A-Z and 0-9. Characters can be repeated but not the string, the string is not generated again.

Comment: What do you mean by "unique"? No repeating characters? The whole string is never generated a second time? If the latter, in what context - on a page? On a server? Across multiple unconnected clients? Something else?

Comment: It can have repeating characters and on server

Comment: OK, so can you just do something like `num = 10000` and then `getUnique() { return String(num++) }`?

Comment: But doesnt that work on arrays only?

Comment: No, you can turn numbers to strings, too: https://jsbin.com/lotezegeno/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1):

**I guess that's what you want. It pops out the character after taken to the string so it can't be taken out again, which guarantees the uniqueness.**

```
function makeid(length) {
     var result           = '';
     var characters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
     var charactersLength = characters.length;
     for (var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
       var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength);
       while (randomIndex > charactersLength) {
         var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength);
         }
         result += characters[randomIndex];
         if (randomIndex > -1) {
           characters.splice(randomIndex, 1);
           }
            }
                return result;
}
```